# Magento 2 add custom field in customer billing and shipping form

Tags: magento2, shipping, billing-address

I want to add custom dropdown field in customer address form of shipping and billing and also customer can add address in checkout so I need to add that custom field in checkout shipping /billing form as well.

How could i able to do this? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

[Click here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html) Magento doc for the same.

Comment: @Ajay.Where do we need to save the Step 1 code?Can you please provide the path.

Answer (score 0):

There are complete tutorials on this from Oye Network. New field creation, saving into the database, and even displaying on the admin side. [Click Here](https://oyenetwork.com/articles/magento2-devliery-date-module-creation-from-scratch/)